# how read data JSON with request.body

Tags: jquery, python, json, django-views

I receive json from jquery:

```
dataJSON = urllib.unquote(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
print dataJSON
horarios=[{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0},{"horario":"6_20_23","estado":0}]
```

I try to read the data with for:

```
for key in dataJSON:
    print key
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

dataJSON = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))

for key in dataJSON:
    print key
```

i'm not sure if you need `urllib.unquote` i.e `dataJSON = json.loads(urllib.unquote(request.body.decode("utf-8")))`, try both and see

Comment: both throw me the following error: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: edit your question and add the request.body content that you receive, maybe some string or space character is present there

Answer (score 0):

solved what follows:

```
dataJSON2 = []
dataJSON = urllib.unquote(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
dataJSON2 = dataJSON[9:]
dataJSON2 = json.loads(dataJSON2)
for key in dataJSON2:
    print key['horario']
```